# kMeans Clustering using TF2.0, ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement simple k-means clustering using TensorFlow 2.0. It is expected that functions decorated with `@tf.function` including those with for loops be converted using autograph.

Please let me know what is causing the ValueError.

**tf_kmeans.py**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Union

@tf.function
def train_kmeans(X: Union[tf.Tensor, np.ndarray], 
    k: Union[int, tf.Tensor], 
    n_iter: Union[int, tf.Tensor] = 10) -> (tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor):

    X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
    X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
    assert len(tf.shape(X)) == 2, "Training data X must be represented as 2D array only"
    m = tf.shape(X)[0]

    k = tf.convert_to_tensor(k, dtype=tf.int64)

    random_select = tf.random.shuffle(X)
    init_centroids = random_select[:k]

    centroids = tf.Variable(init_centroids)
    clusters = tf.zeros([m, ], dtype=tf.int64)
    clusters = tf.Variable(clusters)
    for _ in tf.range(n_iter):
        squared_diffs = tf.square(X[None, :, :] - centroids[:, None, :])
        euclidean_dists = tf.reduce_sum(squared_diffs, axis=-1) ** 0.5

        clusters.assign(tf.argmin(euclidean_dists, axis=0))

        selector = tf.range(k)[:, None] == clusters[None, :]

        for c in tf.range(k):
            select = selector[c]
            points = X[select]
            mean_points = tf.reduce_mean(points, axis=0)
            centroids[c].assign(mean_points)

    centroids = tf.convert_to_tensor(centroids)
    return centroids, clusters
```

The following code is used to call the function:

**tf_means_test.py**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[ 2., 10.],
    [ 2.,  5.],
    [ 8.,  4.],
    [ 5.,  8.],
    [ 7.,  5.],
    [ 6.,  4.],
    [ 1.,  2.],
    [ 4.,  9.]])
k = 3

import tf_kmeans
centroids, clusters = tf_kmeans.train_kmeans(X, k)

print(centroids)
print(clusters)
```

Error message is provided below.

```py
2020-04-11 00:58:33.140511: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-04-11 00:58:33.217765: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7ffc4f310c50 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-11 00:58:33.217798: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_kmeans_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    centroids, clusters = tf_kmeans.train_kmeans(X, k)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 708, in _call
    return function_lib.defun(fn_with_cond)(*canon_args, **canon_kwds)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2419, in __call__
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:700 fn_with_cond  *
        functools.partial(self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    /Users/swg/Repositories/UG-Courses/CSE2705/tf_kmeans.py:21 train_kmeans  *
        centroids = tf.Variable(init_centroids)
    /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:261 __call__  **
        return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:255 _variable_v2_call
        shape=shape)
    /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:66 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /Users/swg/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:511 invalid_creator_scope
        "tf.function-decorated function tried to create "

    ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

If the `tf.function` decorator is removed, the code works perfectly fine because autograph is not executed in that case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want an instance of `tf.Variable` only to use `assign`. However, when using `tf.function`, you should **always** provide variables from outside, and use built-in TensorFlow data structures inside.

For example, your code with minimal changes, without `tf.Variable` objects would be:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Union

@tf.function
def train_kmeans(X: Union[tf.Tensor, np.ndarray], 
    k: Union[int, tf.Tensor], 
    n_iter: Union[int, tf.Tensor] = 10) -> (tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor):

    X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
    X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)

    # Required as an int later
    num_centers = k

    assert len(tf.shape(X)) == 2, "Training data X must be represented as 2D array only"
    m = tf.shape(X)[0]

    k = tf.convert_to_tensor(k, dtype=tf.int64)

    random_select = tf.random.shuffle(X)
    init_centroids = random_select[:k]

    centroids = init_centroids
    clusters = tf.zeros([m, ], dtype=tf.int64)

    for _ in tf.range(n_iter):
        squared_diffs = tf.square(X[None, :, :] - centroids[:, None, :])
        euclidean_dists = tf.reduce_sum(squared_diffs, axis=-1) ** 0.5

        clusters = tf.argmin(euclidean_dists, axis=0)

        selector = tf.range(k)[:, None] == clusters[None, :]

        # TF data structure
        new_centroids = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, num_centers, element_shape=[1, 2])
        for c in range(k):
            select = selector[c]
            points = X[select]
            centroid = tf.reduce_mean(points, axis=0)
            centroid = tf.reshape(centroid, [1, 2])
            new_centroids.write(tf.cast(c, tf.int32), centroid)
        centroids = new_centroids.concat()
        centroids = tf.reshape(centroids, [num_centers, 2])

    return centroids, clusters
```

Comment: The TensorArray always returns 0s only which is fixed using 
`new_centroids = new_centroids.write...`

Comment: Final implementation available here: https://github.com/swghosh/UG-Courses/blob/master/CSE2705/tf_kmeans.py